# Property setter value type is not assignable to the getter return type "str" is incompatible with "datetime"

Tags: python, datetime, setter

Just writing a setter for a class instance attribute and Pylance is showing this as an issue for the `val` parameter of the setter method. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
    def __init__(
                 self, 
                 start_date: str,
                 end_date: str,
                 ) -> None:
        self.start_date = start_date
        
    @property
    def start_date(self) -> dt.datetime:
        return self.__start_date
    
    @start_date.setter
    def start_date(self, val: str) -> None:
        try:
            self.__start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(val, "%Y-%m-%d")
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            logger.exception('Error converting start date to datetime object! '
                             'Cannot continue.')
            raise
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it Pylance being weird as it often does?

Comment: `self.start_date` and `self.__start_date`. same or different variable?

Comment: @sittsering, different variables. This is mostly to avoid the end user from manually changing the value of date properties without going through setter.